# name columns of list element with same name

Tags: r, list, lapply

my code is like the following:

```
unemp <- c(1:10)
bsp_li <- list(c(1:10),c(11:20),c(21:30))
var_data_rep <- lapply(bsp_li, function(x) {cbind(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(unemp))} )
var_data_rep2 <- lapply(var_data_rep, function(x) {colnames(x) = c("rGDP", "U")} )
```

but it does not what i wanted. i would like to name always the two elements of the list `var_data_rep` with `c("rGDP", "U")`. but instead the values are overwritten by `c("rGDP", "U")` and becomes the sole elements of the list.. can anyone help? i need the same names because i want to estimate always the same model later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix: put the names in as the matrices are created:

```
var_data_rep <- lapply(bsp_li, function(x) {
  cbind(rGDP = as.numeric(x), U = as.numeric(unemp))
} )
```

More roundabout fix (why your attempt didn't work): functions return the last line. You want to return `x`, not `colnames(x)`

```
var_data_rep2 <- lapply(var_data_rep, function(x) {
  colnames(x) = c("rGDP", "U")
  return(x)
} )
```

Fancy fix: use the `colnames<-` function directly

```
var_data_rep3 = lapply(var_data_rep, `colnames<-`, c("rGDP", "U"))
```